# Peugeot 307 CC with power folding mirrors - Replacing Passenger side window motor

Tags: electrical, power-windows, peugeot

I have a 2006 peugeot 307 CC. My front passenger side window motor works now and then, but grinds, and only goes up in 1" stages. Also, the roof only opens part way, then stops. I have had an auto electrician say he “thinks” it’s the actual motor, though I’d not been aware of the roof problem at the time. Now that I’ve noticed the roof, the Peugeot agents say it sounds like it’s the motor as they are connected, but at £90.00 just to look, haven’t seen it yet.

The part costs £200, and 3.5 x £80.00 an hour to fit it, plus the £90.00 to check the motor, so, at over £500.00, it’s way too much for me to afford. I’ve been looking on eBay etc. and there are motors available, but not for the power fold mirror type like mine is. Question is, if I get one that’s not wired for the power fold mirrors, would the motor and roof still work? I can cope without one folding mirror if it would.

Comment: Just a thought but how can one electric motor power separate devices... each mirror and the sun roof should have separate independent motors so replacing a mirror motor shouldn't effect the sun roof?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest your best bet is to either speak to a mechanic you trust about it or get down to your nearest breakers yard and show them the part. Also Googling the part number can sometimes give some good results.

To answer your question directly, if you don't get the part from a car that matches your cars specification then there is a high chance something will end up not working.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMWooPWFBLs&t=106s

Anyone with the same problem. Please goto this youtube and have a look. Maybe the problem is in the window switch...Callum Douglass

Exactly the same things happened to me and fixed it at no cost with about 30 mins work

Comment: Great video! Please describe briefly in your answer what the window is showing, just in case the video disappears. :)